# Theme Customization through admin panel. (Appearance-Customize)

Tags: customization, themes

When i customize my wordpress site's theme through customization settings in appearance menu at the admin panel, will the settings lost after i update my theme.

I am aware with the usage of child theme, deciding to use the child theme together with the customization at the Appearance Customize Screen, is this approach recommended?

(Note: i customized the theme through admin panel, Appearance Customize Screen, NOT BY EDITING SOURCE CODE OF THE THEME!).

Thanks in advance.